# Description on custom module

Tags: odoo, manifest

why my description that I built on my manifest file doesn't appear on my custom module in odoo 16?

This is my code:

```
{

    'name': 'Ufa Aurora Guciano',
    'version': '1.0',
    'summary': '1911522018',
    'description': """
        Nama : Ufa Aurora Guciano
        NIM : 1911522018
        Kelas : ERP-C 
    """,
    'author': 'ufaaurora',
    'company': 'Ufa Aurora Guciano',
    'website': 'https://www.uag.com',
    'category': 'Customization',
    'depends': ['base'],
    'data': [
        # 'security/ir.model.access.csv',


    ],
    'application': True,
}
```

And the result is:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDAPR.png)

Answer (score 4):

The `description` is not shown because you set [application](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/16.0/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_module.py#L206) to `True`

```
source=module.description if not module.application and module.description else ''
```

If you look at the [_get_desc](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/16.0/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_module.py#L181-L207) function, you will see that you can add the description to an HTML file under `static/description/index.html`